# Upgrade php to 5.6 in Vagrant provisioning

Tags: vagrant, upgrade, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I upgraded php to 5.6 within the Vagrant box 'trusty64', and also installed SOAP client. When I next update Vagrant I'm thinking it might overwrite these changes. Would I also need to change the provisioning in the vagrantfile, and if so what should I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I next update Vagrant I'm thinking it might overwrite these
>   changes.

No, You would not loose anything if you upgrade vagrant. Once the VMs are created, vagrant will operate those VMs and upgrading vagrant will not impact the existing VM.

Basically, it works like this:
- when you run `vagrant up`, vagrant clone the box (which is VM files) and add the VM to VirtualBox
- after the VM have been created, vagrant "operates" (i.e. start, stop ...) the VirtualBox VM for you

> Would I also need to change the provisioning in the vagrantfile

Thats necessary to change the provisioning if you plan to create more VM of this kind, or if you will destroy and recreate this VM; in this case the provisioning will run and you would need to have it updated.

> and if so what should I add?

save all the commands you have run to run the upgrade and create a shell script out of it, might be the most simple option. You can also look at more advanced tool (puppet, ansible, chef .... that would do this job)

Comment: Thanks, I don't need to create more VM at this time, but it's good to know in case I decide to do it.